# How can I make "smart" macros in Lyx?

Tags: lyx

I want to make "smart macros," in the sense that I can write something like \mat3 in lyx and it turns into a 3x3 matrix, while \mat4 turns into a 4x4 matrix. Instead of writing out each macro for each number, is there a way to define this symbolically? (like \matn becomes an nxn matrix for a positive integer n).

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible. There are some feature requests for this. The easiest thing to do is to make shortcuts for the LyX command that does what you want, but you would have to have a different shortcut for a 4x4 matrix than a 3x3 matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I could find is:
Entering command mode (`Alt+x`) and typing:

`math-matrix` `n` `m`

To create a matrix of m-by-n.